# Count of NULLS in IF condition

Tags: mysql, sql, count, group-by, sum

I have this query :

```
    SELECT 

    SUM(IF(b.correct = 1,1,0)) correct_answers,
    SUM(IF(b.correct != 1,1,0)) incorrect_answers,
    SUM(IF(a.answer IS NULL) 1,0)) as no_answers,
    a.ID
    FROM `a` join b on a.answer  = b.id 
    where a.created_at between '2014-06-10' and '2014-06-17' 
    group by a.ID order by correct_answers desc
```

Basically I am trying to fetch the number of correct , incorrect and no answers for a quiz per user . So I am getting the correct and incorrect counts. But when I try to count the number of no answers (answer column is NULL in table a) I am getting it all zeros. Anything wrong with this query ?

Comment: missing comma and bracket in `SUM(IF((a.answer IS NULL) ,1,0))`

Comment: Can you show your database structure.You are joining table a with column answer,So Null values are already excluded by join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(b.correct = 1) correct_answers,
       SUM(b.correct != 1) incorrect_answers,
       SUM(a.answer IS NULL) AS no_answers,
       a.ID
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.answer = b.id 
WHERE a.created_at BETWEEN '2014-06-10' AND '2014-06-17' 
GROUP BY a.ID 
ORDER BY SUM(b.correct = 1) DESC;
```

Comment: SUM(a.answer IS NULL) is perfect :)

Answer (score 0):

You missed a ',' int the 3rd Line

Change :

```
 SUM(IF(a.answer IS NULL) 1,0)) as no_answers,
```

To:

```
 SUM(IF(a.answer IS NULL, 1,0)) as no_answers,
```

Answer (score 0):

Correct this like

```
SUM(IF(a.answer IS NULL), 1,0)) as no_answers
```

instead of

```
SUM(IF(a.answer IS NULL) 1,0)) as no_answers
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query looks correct for what you are describing.  Here is a possible simplification along with a `left join`:

```
SELECT SUM(b.correct = 1) correct_answers,
       SUM(b.correct <> 1) incorrect_answers,
       SUM(a.answer IS NULL) as no_answers,
       a.ID
FROM `a` left join
      b
      on a.answer  = b.id 
where a.created_at between '2014-06-10' and '2014-06-17' 
group by a.ID
order by correct_answers desc;
```

The `if` statements are unnecessary in MySQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
SUM(IF(b.correct = 1,1,0)) correct_answers,
SUM(IF(b.correct != 1,1,0)) incorrect_answers,
SUM(IF(a.answer IS NULL,1,0)) as no_answers,     <-- You missed a comma here. So, it was always evaluating to 0.
a.ID
FROM `a` join b on a.answer  = b.id 
where a.created_at between '2014-06-10' and '2014-06-17' 
group by a.ID order by correct_answers desc
```